# "csgo_linux64" is not responding

Tags: games, steam

I have encountered this problem after CS:GO updated to "Danger Zone". Before that everything worked fine.

Now it says: "csgo_linux64" is not responding. You may choose to wait a short while for it to continue or force the application to quit entirely.

My system: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS 64-bit; Mesa 18.2.2

Comment: Same issue for me

Comment: I'm getting this as well on Arch Linux. But if I wait a few seconds--usually no more than 30--I can alt-tab to the csgo window and play normally.

Except that, the same time this started, after 4-5 games my video gets really choppy.

Answer (score 10):

When you get options. **Force Quit** and **Wait**, press on **Wait**. Sometimes the dialog box opens again with same options, press *wait* again

Comment: In my case waiting doesn't help, because when CSGO is loaded, I don't get a green button to connect.

Comment: Doesn't help...